# List<List<Object>> sorting

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

I am facing an issue while sorting `List<List<Object>>`. I have created a Custom Comparator where i have written the code to sort the data.

```
 public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<List<Object>> 
    {
    static int i = 0;
    public int compare(List<Object> o1, List<Object> o2) {
            if (i < o1.size()) {
                System.out.println(i);
                Object obj1 = o1.get(i);
                Object obj2 = o2.get(i);
                if (obj1 != null && obj2 != null) {
                    int value = compareTo(obj1.toString(), obj2.toString());
                    if (value == 0) {
                        i++;
                        compare(o1, o2);
                    }
                    return value;
                }
                if (obj1 == null && obj2 != null) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (obj1 != null && obj2 == null) {
                    return 1;
                }
                if (obj1 == null && obj2 == null) {
                    i++;
                    compare(o1, o2);
                }
            }
            else{
                i=0;
            }
        return 0;
    }

    public int compareTo(String value1, String value2) {
        return value1.compareTo(value2);
    }
}
```

Logic that i am trying to implement is that first it will try to sort the using the Object at 0th position. If the values at 0th position is equal or null then it will sort using the Object at 2nd position.etc.
If either of the values are null then that element will be shifted downward. 
However when i try to sort using the code that I have written it gets sort but  neither in ascending or descending order. It is just shuffled.

Comment: I wouldn't put that static i in the comparator class. That is bad practice. In a multithreaded env, you would end up with some really weird behaviors.

Comment: do you want to sort the lists with respect to each other ?? or just sort a particular list in ascending or descending independently ??

Comment: I want to sort a particular list in ascending order

Comment: Also I want to sort the list...so elements inner list in List<List<Object>> shouldn't change

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to use recursion here. Just iterate over the two `List`s in a loop to compare their elements.

Your recursive implementation doesn't work since you ignore that value returned by the recursive calls. The use of a static variable for keeping the index is also a bad idea. What will happen if your `Comparator` instance is used by two threads concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public int compare(List<Object> o1, List<Object> o2) {
   public int compare(List<Object> o1, List<Object> o2) {
      int i=0;
      //TODO validation here for null check
      while(i< o1.size()){
           Object obj1 = o1.get(i);
           Object obj2 = o2.get(i);
            if (obj1 == null && obj2 != null) {
                return -1;
            }else if (obj1 != null && obj2 == null) {
                return 1;
            }else if(obj1 != null && obj2 != null){
                int value = compareTo(obj1.toString(), obj2.toString());
                if(value!=0){
                      return value;
                }
            }
            i++;
      }
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: y have you used while loop?

Comment: if obj1 and obj2 are null then it will check for the next object in each.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
       List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
       a.add("c");
       a.add("a");

       List<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
       b.add("h");
       b.add("b");

       list.add(a);
       list.add(b);

       Collections.sort(list,new Comparator<List<String>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(List<String> o1, List<String> o2) {

            Collections.sort(o1);
            Collections.sort(o2);

            //Compare your list based on your criteria
        }

       });
   }
```